# Scripting.Filesystemobject filemove, writefile not working from javascript in IE browser (workarounds, doc?)

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer, filesystemobject

I know it's a huge security hole to use Scripting.Filesystemobject from javascript in the browser.  I heard a rumor that MS is locking down this hole in the latest version of Office.  This would be bad news for the enterprise web app I am working on, which has a few critical functions which depend on access to Scripting.Filesystem object, like writing out xml files or moving audio files.

I have tried but failed to find any 'hard' documentation on this, and while my local dev box exhibits this behavior, others' machines here (which do not have latest version of anything except IE) do not exhibit the behavior.  If anyone can point me towards documentation confirming this - and or a workaround that does not involve creating an activeX control - I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This article [kb240797](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/240797) discusses IE kill bits.  In the registry you will find this key:-

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility

Under which you will find a set of CLSIDs (the CLSID for FileSystemObject is: {0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}).  If the "Compatibility Flags" value has the bit 1024 (0x400) on (the kill bit) the activex component is blocked.

I've also heard that MS have or are planning to kill FileSystemObject but I haven't seen this officially and it isn't true on my current system.  However it could be that they may internaly block it such a way that even fiddling with the kill bit won't help.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I had checked this before and the only "Flags" value under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Stats\{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}\iexplore was "Flags" and set to 0. I searched the entire registry for all entries pertaining to that CLSID but didn't find any "compatibility flags" entry.  What I find especially interesting is that I cannot write new files, but if I attempt to move an existing file (created with an AX component), the prior axiom results in my file disappearing (since it gets moved from its location but not into the new one).

Comment: Are you sure you're not barking up the wrong tree.  Sounds to me like a plain old file permissions problem to me.

Comment: That could be, tho' I am admin on the box.  All this stuff worked before installing updates, which is my biggest clue that it's not permissions. I've tried rolling back the updates but that just really messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I've heard nothing along the lines of `FileSystemObject` being deprecated.  I'd love to see your sources for this.  Another thing to note is that the last "major" ActiveX control to be deprecated for being a security risk was CAPICOM, but this was announced with the release of Vista and finally removed in Windows 7.   The documentation was also changed to reflect this deprecation and *suggest* alternatives well in advance.

*Many* (MANY!) shell scripts rely on `FileSystemObject` for file operations, so I find it hard to believe it would be deprecated without an alternative being provided.  If it makes a difference, `FileSystemObject` is still accessible from Windows Desktop Gadgets which run on the IE engine.

Comment: Please see comments from Mr. Jiang 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f

Comment: @Alexx: Indeed, that is interesting and I'm glad you found an answer to your question.  I will try to be more helpful next time you have an ActiveX related question ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You wouldn't, shouldn't **ever** access the users files system through a browser, for legit or illegit reasons.

The very, very best case example of accessing local storage is done through systems like Google Gears, and even those systems are often argued against by web/thin client purists.

Comment: altCognito, <heavy sigh> I know this.  I didn't design this app, came into it on this gig.  Just looking for viable interim solutions while we 'make it real'. Thanks for the hint on google gears.

Comment: Never say never.  Not all browser apps are running on web servers or are outside of firewalls.  (And no, it was not me who down-voted your answer.)