# Ajax file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, activexobject

I want to move file from one directory to another.

I get all the files, and the size of each file, but when I verify if the file exists via ajax, there is always going to error result. I did not use ajax too much, but if I get all the information I need, why I can't move the files?

Here is the code I use:

```
moveErrorFiles('C:/Users/romama/Desktop/HMI Versions/V 0.5/web/css');

function moveErrorFiles(fileDir){
    var fileSysObj, file, folder, fileCounter, currentFile;

    fileSysObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    folder = fileSysObj.GetFolder(fileDir);
    fileCounter = new Enumerator(folder.files);

    for (; !fileCounter.atEnd(); fileCounter.moveNext()) {
        currentFile = fileCounter.item();

        file = fileSysObj.GetFile(currentFile)
        checkFileExist(file, file.Size);
    }
}

function checkFileExist(fileToMove, size) {
    $.ajax({
        url: fileToMove,
        type: 'HEAD',
        contentType: 'image/png',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        error: function() {
            console.log(fileToMove + "\nthis file doesn't exist... Size = " + size);
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log(fileToMove + '\nthis file exists... Size = ' + size);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the output in the IE console:

```
C:\Users\romama\Desktop\HMI Versions\V 0.5\web\css\style.css
this file doesn't exist... Size = 13823
C:\Users\romama\Desktop\HMI Versions\V 0.5\web\css\styleSmall.css
this file doesn't exist... Size = 13634
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what ajax does. Ajax is used to communicate with a webserver using HTTP method, which some random local file won't support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scripting.Filesystemobject filemove, writefile not working from javascript in IE browser (workarounds, doc?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139982/scripting-filesystemobject-filemove-writefile-not-working-from-javascript-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

That's against the rules of the browser.

You can read the metadata but won't be able to modify/delete the files.

Like Rich said, it would be a security flaw.

*Just imagine you visit a site www.goofup.com, just to know that the site deleted your operating system.*

You surely won't want that.

Comment: I tried to do fileToMove.Move('C:/Users/romama/Desktop/HMI Versions/V 0.5/web/css/files');, but it says the file already exists.

Comment: LIke I said you can't modify/remove or even move them.

Comment: is it any possibility to do this operation using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't do such operations in JS or jQuery or any other client side scripting language, inside a browser

Comment: Javascript being able to modify local file systems would be a **huge** security vulnerability.

Comment: Yeah agreed with @Rich

Answer (score 0):

You can check if file exist or not by this function also. You do not need to use `AJAX` Call.

```
    function UrlExists(url)
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status!=404;
    }
```

Use this function if that AJAX is not ur only requirement.